# Issue in substituting values in a string in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python. I am trying to form SQL insert query as follows:

```
table_name = kwargs['table_name']
sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
params = []
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    params.append([v, k])

for param in params:
     sql = sql % param <---IN THIS LINE I AM GETTING ERROR TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I know here it is treating param as a single item, that's why I am getting this issue, but I am not getting how to solve this.

Basically in each iteration I want to form following insert sql query:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (k1, v1)
```

I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` substitution recognize multiple parameter only it is instance of `tuple`(or `dict` for named substitution). 
So try this:

```py
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    params.append((v, k))
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=string%20interpolation#printf-style-string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use `sql = sql % (param[1],param[0])` instead of `sql = sql % param`

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

```
table_name = kwargs['table_name']
sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (col1, col2) VALUES "
params = []

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    params.append("({}, {})".format(k, v))

sql += ', '.join(params)

print(sql)
```

This way, you are sure to add a `('<value 1>', '<value 2>')` string to the query for each and every element in your dict of values.